# Flash Builder 4.5 (Mobile) - Rolling out Database Updates

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.5

This is my first question on here so please be kind lol.

I am working on a mobile application with Flash Builder 4.5.

It uses a custom sql-lite database (tables are created on program load if they don't exist) to store the data. The data gets inserted by a sync process which connects to a web service.

I'm looking to ensure that changes to the database tables won't break the program.

For example I need to add a new field to an existing database table. I already know the SQL command (ALTER TABLE) for this but I'm not sure how to tie this to the update of the program i.e. when upgrading the program to 0.1 it should add the new field. But obviously I don't want it to try and add the field more than once.

Is there any way of knowing inside the program when it has been updated by the android/ios stores? Or any suggestions on how to handle these database changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer has helped point me in the right direction:

[database updates answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614728/add-column-to-sqlite-db-if-not-exists-flex-air-sqlite)