# does ALTER TABLE conflict with IF TABLE NOT EXIST

Tags: flash, sqlite, air

If you use ALTER TABLE to alter a SQLite db, will there be a conflict when the app loads again as  it checks to see if the table exists with the original 4 columns and then creates it?  Will it see the new table as a different one because it has extra columns, and recreate it and rewrite the old one to go back to having 4 columns again?

I have a list of student names and I want a teacher to input attendance records. I was going to use ALTER TABLE to add the date of the attendance record to the existing table that only starts with 4 columns (ID, first name, last name, teacher).  Should I just create a new table without the IF NOT EXISTS code?

Thank you!

Update
    {
    var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stat.sqlConnection = conn;
    stat.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sections (                          " +
                          "id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,      " + 
                          "grade        TEXT,                                   " +
                          "teacher      TEXT,                                   " + 
                          "firstname    TEXT,                                   " +
                          "lastname     TEXT,                                   " +
                          "gender       TEXT)";
    stat.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onCreate);
    stat.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onDBError);
    stat.execute(); 
}

Comment: How are does your code check for the table?

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` only creates the table if the table with the given *name* does not exist. It does not look at the columns.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614728/add-column-to-sqlite-db-if-not-exists-flex-air-sqlite?rq=1) for one approach to database versioning.